# Job tech preferences has unintuitive UI

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, user-interface, user-experience, profile-page

edit: this is on the page `https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/<uid>`

There's no visual indication at all that there are selected technologies ABOVE what is shown; there's no scrollbar and the box is sized small enough to not imply that more values *could* be there.  Is there a way to improve how this is shown visually so I can tell I have additional values I apparently have to use the keyboard to arrow-up to see?

<strike>I really want to be able to highlight C and C++ jobs.  However, when I type either C or C++ in the "Tech you want to work with", it does not show me that match nor let me save.  How do I do this?</strike>

(same behavior seen in both Chrome and Firefox...)

[image: My sad settings]

Comment: Both [tag:c] and [tag:c++] work for me on OS X Chrome 64.0.3282.186

Comment: Are you on the jobs page, or some other page?  C and C++ work on things like "favorite tags", just not on the jobs preferences page.

Comment: Yep, job preferences, tech you do and don't want to work with as shown in your screenshot (`https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/<userid>`). Are you sure they're not already in the list but cut off from that display?

Comment: OMG.  That's it.  There's no indication that those fields scroll or that I'm at the bottom of the list.