# How do I edit Roles on Stack Overflow Job preferences?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, user-experience

I don't seem to be able to add new Roles to the Roles box. I've found [a list of roles](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/directory/jobs-by-role) that should be available, and typing things that look like they should match don't seem to do anything.

I would have expected an experience similar to [this one for tech preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363960/job-tech-preferences-has-unintuitive-ui). Fwiw, that interface *does* work for me.

[image: I'm typing "desktop" for "Desktop developer jobs", but when I tab away, it disappears]

In the above image, I'm typing "desktop" for "Desktop developer jobs", but no pop-ups appear, and when I tab away, the typing disappears.<sup>*</sup>

Maybe I can only have two roles max, but without a note saying as much, I'm afraid if I remove one, I'll have one less than I have now and still not be able to add anything.

Not sure if `[bug]` (should see something) or `[user-experience]` (can only have two, but no cue that's the case). Have both tags currently.

---

<sup>* Note: I'm testing. I don't actually want to add "Desktop developer jobs" permanently.</sup>

Comment: I’ve noticed this before. It seems you can only have two. I have no idea why this artificial limitation exists.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks. Yeah, that's not great -- and even if that's intended, seems there should be some cue to tell you two's the limit other than, "Forget it. Not going to give you any indication your editing's doing anything."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit of two, which will now be shown above the input field. 
[image: Screenshot of limit description]

Previously, it was shown in the placeholder which was hidden when you selected a value.

Comment: Thank you very much! `/hat tip`